# Limitations of SQLITE on Android - 25 tables with 15 column each and 10k rows per table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to build an application on a Tablet. The application is going to be data intensive. Does SQLite support 25 tables with 15 column each and about 10k rows per table?

It would be great if someone could point out the limitations. I have been to the other links posted to SQlite.org, but they were not of much help.

Comment: Im interested in seeing how something this heavy would perform on a mobile device.
Post some follow up regarding performance if you can.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no limit set on the size of a database as long as it fits in the memory. However there are some known issues, read up on those [here](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)